# How to enable Zapier OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow using RingCentral API

Tags: oauth-2.0, zapier, ringcentral

I've built a Zapier integration using Zapier's built-in OAuth 2.0 implementation with the RingCentral API. The integration works well for launching the OAuth 2.0 dialog, getting the access token, and calling the required API. However, the token refresh isn't working so after 1 hour the APIs return an unauthorized user error and the user is required to login again. 1 hour is quite a bit of time so it's slow debug after manually logging in again.

I couldn't find Zapier logging for the Refresh Token API flow so I can't tell if it's being called and, if so, what is the result and error message.

How can the Refresh Token Flow be enabled and is there a way to debug the Refresh Token Workflow performed by Zapier?

Here's info on Zapier for the OAuth 2.0 flow:

https://platform.zapier.com/docs/oauth#add-access-token-request-and-refresh-token-request-urls

Here's the information on the RingCentral API for the refresh token flow:

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Get-Token

This is what the Zapier OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Request UI looks like with the RingCentral API information:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Basic Authentication Required

I found it. The missing requirement for the RingCentral API from the default Zapier OAuth implementation is Basic Authentication in Token Refresh Flow. Zapier includes the Basic Auth `Authorization` header for the initial Authorization Code Flow but not for the Refresh Token Flow.

I ended up pre-computing the `Authorization` header field and manually inserting it into the Refresh Token Flow Request using "Switch to Code Mode" where I added the `Authorization` header as follows:

```js
const options = {
  url: 'https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic <Base64EncodedClientIdAndClientSecret>'
  },
  params: {

  },
  body: {
    'refresh_token': bundle.authData.refresh_token,
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token'
  }
}
```

Base64 is used to encode the following:

```
process.env.CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
```

At first, I set `Authorization` to the following but received the Zapier error that `btoa` isn't defined.

```js
'Basic ' + btoa(process.env.CLIENT_ID+':'+process.env.CLIENT_SECRET)
```

### Test Cycle Time

I was able to lower the time to refresh for testing by hard coding the `access_token_ttl` value to the minimum value of `600` seconds (10 minutes) vs. the default `3600` seconds (1 hour).

### Zapier Refresh Token Flow Logs

I'm still not able to find Zapier logs for the Zapier Refresh Token Flow.

Without the ability to see if Zapier is actually sending token refresh requests, a way to test this is to temporality set the token refresh URL to a monitoring URL such as RequestBin.